# Non-system applications install automatically on Factory Reset

Tags: android, adb

I want to create an application that preserves its APK file with the ROM and is available (fresh installs) after factory reset.

Logic:

I bought a new phone from an e-commerce website and the phone had the e-commerce's application pre-installed on my phone.

I uninstalled the application but the application re-installed after I did a factory reset.

Uninstalling the application showed that it was a non-system application.
Automatically being re-installed shows it is included with the ROM.

***How do I achieve this?***

Answer (score 0):

Factory reset basically wipes the internal storage and replaces it with a copy.  On some models, you can replace that restore image- but you need the device's boot loader to be unlocked to do that.  Its not a programming thing, its a matter of replacing the restore image with an image including your apk.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to always be included in Device even after factory reset. For that you need to embed your app into that particular ROM, Like all google application comes already embedded in Android ROM.

Also If can develop new ROM from stock one then you can embed your apps too. Like, most of the Chinese and Samsung's TouchWiz ROM comes pre-bundled with their own APPs, instead of that stock one e.g Contacts(System), Messaging(System) and Flipkart(Non-system).